# References concerning $\mathbb{C}[\partial]$-modules?

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

I'm reading the book *Vertex algebras for begginers* by Victor Kac. From certain point on, the book uses the term $\mathbb{C}[\partial]$-module. It is pretty obvious to me what this means, i.e., a $\mathbb{C}[\partial]$-module is a module over the ring of polynomial expressions on $\partial$.

However I would like to read a formal definition and some general properties, but I haven't found any reference dealing with these modules, neither in my university's library or in the web (everything I have found is a mention in the wikipedia's article about [Lie conformal algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_conformal_algebra)). I would appreaciate some good references concerning these modules.

Thanks in advance.